# Android: Button On Click listener: Single and constant when held down

Tags: java, android

I am unsure how to word this right but I want a button / on click listener to do this

1 touch  = 1 tap = generate 1 row 
Hold button down = generate 1 row per seconds or x per second

You know in games like clash of clans when u recruit soldier, u can touch it for 1 soldier or hold it down for more. I want a similar implementation but for a button

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For one single tap to generate 1 row, use:-

```
 Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
       //put your code here for single tap event
    }

  });
```

For long press use the following:-

```
b.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

      //your code here for long press event
    }
  });
```